# how to convert a large number exprimed on several bytes?

Tags: erlang

If a number is exprimed on 4 bytes, from LSB to MSB, how to convert it in integer ?
example:

```
<<77,0,0,0>> shall give 77
```

but

```
<<0,1,0,0>> shall give 256

Let S = <<0,1,0,0>>, 
<<L1,L2,L3,L4>> = S,  
L = L1*1 + L2*256 + L3*65536 + L4*16777216,
```

But it's not elegant ...

Comment: Why don't you just use the binary syntax with `/little` and `/big` qualifiers, as @archaelus did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** (this is the correct answer, and sorry for discovering it late...)

```
> binary:decode_unsigned(<<0,1,0,0>>,little).
256
```

The easier way would be something like:

```
decode_my_binary( <<A,B,C,D>> ) ->
    A + B*256 + C*65536 + D*16777216.
```

**EDIT**:

As per your edit, if you find this one not very elegant, you can try other approaches. Still I think the above is the correct way of doing it. You can write a recursive function (not tested, but you get the idea):

```
decode( B ) -> decode(binary_to_list(B), 0, 1).
decode( [], R, _ ) -> R;
decode( [H|T], R, F) ->
    decode(T, R + H*F, F*256).
```

but this is clearly slower. Another possibility is to have the list of the binary digits and the list of multipliers and then fold it:

```
lists:sum(lists:zipwith( fun(X,Y) -> X*Y end,
                   binary_to_list(B), [ math:pow(256,X) || X <- [0,1,2,3] ])).
```

Or if you want a variable number of digits:

```
fun(Digits) ->
    lists:sum(lists:zipwith( fun(X,Y) -> X*Y end,
                   binary_to_list(B), [ math:pow(256,X) || X <- lists:seq(0,Digits-1])).
```

where `Digits` tell you the digit number.

Comment: Well, I think this is *still* elegant... But not scalable. Anyway, it is easy to be done scalable :)

Comment: Second that. ) @Bertaud - you have a _fixed_ number of bytes to check, yet you still consider a solution with _fixed_ number of cycles inferior somehow?

Comment: Elegant means for me efficient.Yes, a fixed number.

Answer (score 9):

The [bit syntax](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77874) in Erlang does this in a very straightforward way:

```
<<A:32/little>> = <<0,1,0,0>>,
A.
% A = 256
```

or as a function:

```
decode(<<Int:32/little>>) -> Int.

% decode(<<0,1,0,0>>) =:= 256.
```